# How to add a custom permission to a group in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I think I have coded a custom permission in a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = [('admin_foo', 'Can administrate foo'),]
    ...
```

I ran the commands to store the permission:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then I have a decorator on my protected view:

```
@permission_required('app.admin_foo')
def myFooView(request):
    ...
```

How do I add this permission to the group "bar" programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename=perm_name)
group.permissions.add(permission)
```